# how to stop authentication required in xampp user

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

[image]
Whenever I'm going to load the `phpmyadmin` the pop-up will appear..
[image]
And this is my `config.ini.php` file

Comment: you mean don't ask for password? try using `'config'` for `auth_type`. More Info [here](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html)

Comment: yes, i need to visite the phpmyadmin with out entering any password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try following this it may help:

In xampp directory there will be a `.htaccess` file that contains the instructions for Apache to ask for authorization. You can rename it, or go into the file and comment out the following lines:

```
AuthName "xampp user"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /opt/lampp/lib/xampp.users
require valid-user
```

Comment: i am in XAMPP not in lampp 
i can find a file lyk you mentioned above

Comment: apache in all OS works the same, the folder you need to look for .htaccess file is the parent folder of phpmyadmin installation.

Comment: i got that file...
how do i comment that file

Comment: **AuthName "xampp user"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "C:\xampp\security\xampp.users"
require valid-user **

Comment: which simbol i have to use ';' '//'

Comment: use ; to comment .this is what i use for comment in my ubuntu.

Comment: k i just use /*  */ block comment methed 

now it is fine thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

Quote from documentation:

> ‘config’ authentication ($auth_type = 'config') is the plain old way:
>   username and password are stored in config.inc.php.

and set

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'username_to_connect_to_db';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password_for_db';
```

Quote:

> When using $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] set to ‘config’, this is
>   the user/password-pair which phpMyAdmin will use to connect to the
>   MySQL server. This user/password pair is not needed when HTTP or
>   cookie authentication is used and should be empty.

Reference : [phpMyAdmin configuration](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html)

Comment: also you may require @suchit's suggestion, if you find any .htaccess file.